# nativescript magnetometer data access with javascript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, magnetometer

how can I access the magnetometer data on iOS or Android through NativeScript without using native APIs? Just looking to get a simple heading reading.
I'm using the JavaScript framework for development

Answer (score 0):

Well we have the [Core Motions](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-coremotion) plugin already, did you try that?

As per plugin's author, these sensors are not yet available for Android, neither I found any official docs on that.

Comment: Thanks, I’m aware of the plugin but as you mentioned Android is not supported and while I would like to be able to develop a cross platform app, Android is what I need for now. The accelerometer plugin from npm works well but I’m just looking for a simple way to access compass heading so I can get full device orientation for an AR application that I’m trying to build. Is there a way to access the javascript HTML5 devicemotion event handler inside NativeScript?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use nativescript-webview-interface plugin to communicate between WebView and your native app.